# How to better structure linear algebra-heavy code in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, architecture, linear-algebra

Need some suggestions on scaling a pipeline on spark that performs Collaborative Filtering for about 200k-1m people, but does so in groups, with the largest group being approx. 40-50k customers at best. In addition to Collaborative Filtering, which is reasonably fast with ALS, there's a lot of linear algebra that occurs that I couldn't really figure out how to perform with the spark Dataframe API, and had to drop down to the RDD API to perform, and that leads to a significant loss in performance. I've currently got multiple variations of this script - in scala, pyspark, and python - and by far the fastest, despite not being distributor/parallelized, is python, where I'm using numpy for all linear algebra tasks, and python for the remaining transformations.

So, to summarize, I've got a pipeline with a lot of complicated linear algebra that spark doesn't seem to have performant native data structures for, and the workarounds I've devised - RDDs level manipulations for most operations, parallelizing and broadcasting the RDDs to perform matmul in chunks, etc - are significantly slower than just performing the operations in-memory on numpy.

I've got a couple of ideas on how to scale this, but they are a bit hacky, so I was hoping that somebody more experienced could pitch in.

1. Keep the entire script in python. Used Dask to distribute the processing of various groups of customers in parallel across the cluster.
2. Keep the entire script in python, but run that using pyspark, keeping a pandas UDF as an entry/exit point for various python functions. However, since pandas UDF have certain limitations in that I can only input & output a single dataframe, but my analysis requires multiple datasets, I need to have some workarounds. Here's what I've what figured out:

   - Read all datasets into pyspark. All relevant datasets have same number of rows, indexed with customer and other attributes, so I'll concat each row of a dataset into a single column array. So, basically, the 3-4 datasets become 3-4 columns in a consolidated dataset + a customer index.
   - Transfer this across to python via a pandas UDF.
   - Extract all relevant datasets from this combined structure in python, perform all the operations (around 1000 loc) and resemble the outputs into a similar structure as the input and transfer back to pyspark.
   - Since I used a pandas UDF computations across all groups should have occurred in parallel. This then becomes akin to running a Dask like distributed compute via pyspark.
   - Extract all the data from this consolidated array, map types, and save via pyspark.
   - This is extremely hacky, and has a few downsides, but I think it'll do the job. I realize that I won't really be able to debug the python udf code easily, so that'll be an irritant, and the solution is still fundamentally limited by the size of the largest single executor I can get, but despite that it'll likely perform better native pyspark/scala code.

Any suggestions on how to better structure this, or ideas about how to do more rapid linear algebra on pyspark natively would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the distributed matrix data structures from the MLlib RDD-based API? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.mllib.html#vector-and-matrix